# _LogOnPartial file of a newly created MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In the _LogonPartial.cshtml there is a actionlink for user to log on, I would like to replace `@:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]`with a button or an image i can use onmouseover and onmouseout but I don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account", new { @class = "hover" })`

then use css to place an image on the link and another when the user hovers on it.

```
.hover{  
background: url('/path/to/myImage.png');  
}  
.hover:hover{  
  background: url('/path/to/myOtherImage.png');  
}
```